# Why SampleGrabber::SampleCB only called single time while SetSyncSource(NULL) is not called

Tags: directshow

I wrote a FilterGraph to capture the live videoStreams.
SourceFilter  ---->  SampleGrabber  ----> NullRenderer.
My graph worked fine With Nikon. GoPro cameras. But for OBS it is only returning a single frame means SampleCB is called for once if I don't call IMediaFilter::SetSyncSource(NULL). If I call SetSyncSource(NULL) then with OBS my graph worked fine. But with other devices like Nikon it is not working.

Comment: There are some faulty DirectShow fitlers in the pipeline. No way to give any more details with this problem description. `IMediaFilter::SetSyncSource` is not supposed to affect ability to receive `SampleCB` calls.

Comment: @RomanR. Before calling the run method of the filter graph , I have called SetSyncSource(NULL). And observed OBS engine returns expected number of frames ( SampleCB is called for every frame). If I don't call SetSyncSource(NULL) just before the Rn method, then OBS only returns a single frame (SampleCB is called for single time)

Comment: So OBS might be buggy in some way. However not necessarily OBS. There should be some investigation here, a few years ago I wrote a blog post on what to do next: [Understanding Your DirectShow Filter Graph](https://alax.info/blog/1678)